# How to source vimrc in All buffers

Tags: vim, neovim

To source `vimrc` in all buffers in the current window I do `:bufdo so~/.vimrc` ,to source `vimrc` in the ACTIVE buffers in all windows I do `:windo so~/.vimrc`. How to source `vimrc` in all buffers in all windows?

<strike>for some reason if I do`:bufdo  so~/.vimrc | :windo so~/.vimrc` the active buffer in the non-active window changes.</strike>

**example**: if I set `set number` in my .`vimrc`, I want all buffers in all windows affect the change.

the solution might be something like this:

```
for window in windowlist
        execute 'bufdo so~/.vimrc'
```

I use **vim  8.2** .

**PLEASE NOTE:** I did try all of the commands you guys suggested but it seems that things aren't clear enough. all of the commands that includes `:tabdo` `:windo` `:bufdo` or combination of them doesn't work properly for what I want. please note that this is the same as changing vimrc and sourcing it with chain of these commands like `:tabdo bufdo so~/.vimrc`. for example `:windo bufdo set number` does `set number` to all buffers(active or hidden) in the active window but on non-active windows only does `set number` for the active buffer(buffer that is shown in the window)  or `:tabdo windo set number` only does `set number` in **active** buffers in every window meaning that hidden buffers  won't get line numbers.
I even made a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/iehjcg/how_to_source_vimrc_in_all_buffers/) about this problem on [r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/)  and made a video about it but I don't know  why nobody gets what I say. honestly don't think this problem  will be solved by someone else but  me even though its a simple one.

Answer (score 1):

The `:bufdo` command will consume `|` as part of the command to execute, so in effect you're running the `:windo` command for *each* buffer that you have active!

See [`:help :bar`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar), which documents this behavior.

That help section also mentions a way to work around this behavior, by using the `:execute` command to run the first command from a string, which allows you to delimit the first command. Like so:

```
:execute 'bufdo so ~/.vimrc' | windo so ~/.vimrc
```

Please note that sourcing your vimrc file *"in all buffers"* or *"in all windows"* doesn't make much sense... The vimrc file typically has global commands that usually need to be sourced only once, and usually if you modify your vimrc, sourcing it again only once should be enough...

This *might* make sense with a separate `*.vim` script that affects local settings and is meant to act on a single buffer. The ftplugin, indent and syntax scripts come to mind. But also with those, they're normally run per buffer, not per window... It's not completely inconceivable that you'd have scripts that you want to run on every buffer and window, but it surely seems odd...

Comment: thx for replying. my solution for the problem was fundamentally wrong. `bufdo` only affects buffers in the active window, so `execute ':bufdo so~/.vimrc'  | :windo so~.vimrc ` only affects all buffers in active window and the active buffers in all windows. I think the solution is to loop over every window and execute `bufdo so~/.vimrc`  but I'm not very familiar with vim script.

Comment: *"`bufdo` only affects buffers in the active window"* Well, there's only one buffer list though. If you run `bufdo` on this window, then again on the next window, it will go through the same list of buffers twice. It does **use** the current window to cycle through the buffer list. But I can't see how it might be useful to do that many times for every window you have on the screen. (But then, sourcing your vimrc on every buffer doesn't make much sense either, so...)

Answer (score 1):

`.vimrc` shall only contain global definitions. That the way it's supposed to be used. Sourcing it in several buffers makes no sense.

I wonder if you're fighting with local settings for which the best tool to use is either ftplugin (when the setting are filetype driven), or a local_vimrc plugin for project driven settings.

Comment: Oh sorry. Not _global_ in the sense _shared by all users_, but global in the sense _shared but all buffers and windows_ in a Vim session.

Comment: yeah I figured it out a bit late. mb.

Comment: I think I put it out badly so I hope this example makes my thought a bit clearer. example: if I put `set number` in `.vimrc` I want all the buffers in all windows affect the change. what's the best way to do it?

Comment: The `.vimrc` is expected to contain the settings that shall apply in a new Vim session. If you want to globally change dynamically window-local options like `'number'`, that's were there is `:windo set nu`. Unfortunately, globally changing buffer/window local options a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

To apply in all buffers and all windows:
`:windo bufdo set number`

If you have tabs, from `:tabe`, `:tabf`, `:tab` and friends. Just add `tabdo` like this:
`:tabdo windo bufdo set number`

I would advise not to source your `vimrc` like this. If you want a quick setting, just use the `set` command and friends.

- [`:help tabdo`](https://vimhelp.org/tabpage.txt.html#%3Atabdo)
- [`:help windo`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Awindo)
- [`:help bufdo`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo)
- [`:help source`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#using-scripts)

---

While I agree with most answers on sourcing your `vimrc`. I do believe there are uses of the source command. Particularly batch fixing. I've never tried using
`:windo` with this, I mostly use `:argdo` and `:cdo`. As I have more fine-grained control on what files I need to apply.

Batch fixing is particularly useful on a large codebase. You do your fixes with `:g`, `:v`, `:s` for example, and save them in a file called `fix.vim`. This is so useful, you could even pair macros with those commands (`:g` and `:v`) via `:norm` command.

- [`:help norm`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal)

Then update your argslist via `:args *.js` or similar commands ([like backtick expression](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/populating-the-arglist/)) and finally do the `:argdo source fix.vim`